# how to modify content of a xml file which is on exist db server from java code

Tags: java

I am able to access the xml file content from server but not able to modify

```
final String driver = "org.exist.xmldb.DatabaseImpl";

    Class cl = Class.forName(driver);
    Database database = (Database) cl.newInstance();
    //database.setProperty("create-database", "true");
    DatabaseManager.registerDatabase(database);

    Collection col = null;
    XMLResource res = null;
    try {    
        // get the collection

        col = DatabaseManager.getCollection(URI + "test");
        col.setProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        res = (XMLResource)col.getResource("note.xml");
        if(res == null)
        {
            System.out.println("document not found!");
            return;
        } 

        Document doc=(Document) res.getContentAsDOM();
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        NodeList mainNode = doc.getElementsByTagName("to");
        for(int i=0;i<mainNode.getLength();i++)
        {
            System.out.println(mainNode.item(i).getTextContent());
            mainNode.item(i).setTextContent("John");
            System.out.println(mainNode.item(i).getTextContent());
        }
```

Output:

```
 Tove
 John
```

but when i am again accessing the same xml file, value of "to" element again same as Tove

So i want to change it permanently as John from java code.
How can i achieve it?

Thanks

Comment: May be you have to write it to the server

Comment: but can you tell be How can i do that ?